# Improper integral where both bounds are undefined

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

$$\int_0^\infty{\ln x}\mathrm dx$$ is the integral in question.

Taking the integral, I am not quite sure what to do with the 0, as ln is not defined there. Should I evaluate from 0+?

A related question: what is the proper term that describes improper integrals that have undefined values on both bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite it as $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln x\mathrm dx+\lim_{\delta\to \infty}\int_{1}^{\delta}\ln x\mathrm dx$$

Either way this improper integral is *divergent*.

Comment: Paradoxically with the OP's concerns, the above integral diverges because of $\;\infty\;$ , not because of zero, meaning: for any real $\;t\in\Bbb R\;$ , the integral $\;\int\limits_0^t\;$ converges.